# Two classes containing each other

Tags: java, class

I have two classes in java: X and Y. Y is a member of X, and a list of X is a member of Y.
I need to make sure that they always match eg if x has y then y's list should contain x.
What is the best way to do it? Should setY(y) and addX(x) reference each other?

Comment: Can you add some context to the question to explain the use-case for this feature/functionality?

Comment: I have a summer seminar with three different camps in it. Each camp has a list of childrens, and each children belongs to a camp.

Comment: what have you done. Let's see your class codes. `members` is not a tag

Comment: I would try to define a master/child association here, and always go through the master to modify the association. The rest is encapsulation. Make sure to avoid infinite loops if you want to make it possible to modify the association on both sides.

Comment: @Subs the classes contain other irrelevant code. For the question you can look at it as two POJOs: a Camp with List<Children> as member and a Children with Camp member.

Comment: Y is an inner class of X?  So to make sure the  list of X in Y contains a reference to its class X, just do this in the constructor of Y - passing the reference of X and add it to the X's list in Y.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your comments, what I understand is that:

- You have a `Camp` object which contains a `List<Child>`
- You have a `Child` object which contains a `Camp`

You want to ensure that if the `List<Child>` in some `Camp camp` has a particular `Child`, say `child`, then `child.getCamp()` must be `camp` (and vice-versa ?).

In my opinion, if this needs to be strictly enforced, you should use `Child` as an inner class in `Camp`. You can create a factory method `addChild(params reqd to construct child)` to `Camp`, and have no public constructor for `Child`:

```
public class Camp {
    List<Child> children;
    public Camp() {
        children = new ArrayList<Camp.Child>();
    }

    public void addChild() {
        children.add(new Child(this));
    }

    class Child {
        Camp camp;

        private Child(Camp camp) {
            this.camp=camp;
        }
    }

}
```

Pass any other params required for constructing `Child` to the addChild method as well. I think this suits your case if you want to ensure that there is no child without a camp.

Answer (score 0):

I understood this:

```
public class X{
   private Y yMember;
   public void setY(Y anY){ 
     //edit next line
     if( anY != null && yMember != null ) throw new Exception("already has a parent");
     yMember = anY; 
   }
}

public class Y{
   private List<X> xList;

   public void addX( X anX ){
     //edit next line
     if( X.getY() != null ) throw new ArgumentException("x already in a list");
     anX.setY(this);
     xList.Add(anX);
   }
   public void removeX( X anX ){
     //edit next line
     if( X.getY() != this ) throw new ArgumentException("x not in this list");
     xList.Remove(anX);
     anX.setY(null);
   }
}
```

Is it what you are looking for or can you elaborate more?

Edit: After the comments from JBNizet, I realize, that this is really not a good thing to expose and can be used incorrectly easily. I edited in some exceptions instead of deleting my answer.

Comment: You don't respect Java naming conventions, and your solution doesn't prevent any incoherence: the same X can be in several Ys, a Y may be set to an X without the Y containing this X.

Comment: yep, the methodNames should be lower case and the private members have no leading underscore. thats so c#, pardon me. the second part I don't understand, since I can only add X's to Y's list using the methods add and remove.

Comment: `X x = new X(); x.setY(y);`: x has y as parent, but y doesn't have x as child. `y1.addX(x); y2.addX(x);`: x is the child of y1 and y2, but only has y2 as parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
class X {
  private Y y;

  public void setY(Y y) {
    if (this.y == y) {
      return;
    }

    // todo: remove this instance from the old 'y'.

    this.y = y;

    if (this.y != null) {
      this.y.addX(this);
    }
  }
}

// todo: add functionalitiy to remove an X instance.
class Y {
  private List<X> xs = new ArrayList<X>();

  public X addX(X x) {
    if (x != null) {
      x.setY(this);
      xs.add(x);
    }
    return x;
  }
}
```

A rough sketch on how to implement that. It sounds pretty much like a tree with all nodes knowing there parent.